# What's the best way to specify a key_name for App Engine NDB Model?

Tags: google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb

I'm trying to create an ndb model where each record has an unique field "name". I would like to define this field as the key_name field and use it to look up the records. Do I have to include a name field or can I somehow set the key_name field to an arbitrary string that the user can specify as long as it's unique?

I'm thinking of using Model.get_or_insert to make sure that old records don't get overwritten, but is there a way to tell if the return value is newly created or pre-existing? I want to be able to display an error message if the user entered a duplicate name.

Lastly, I tried to create a key_name field on a DjangoForms model that uses the above ndb model as the metaclass so I can use djangoforms for validation/rendering but for some reason my defined fields don't show up.

class UserProfileForm(djangoforms.ModelForm):
    key_name = djangoforms.StringProperty()
    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile

Comment: You should really ask separate questions for each of these, rather than lumping them all together.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> Do I have to include a name field or can I somehow set the key_name field to an arbitrary string that the user can specify as long as it's unique?

You can pass your your unique key name as the `id` parameter to model constructor: `profile = UserProfile(id='my_unique_name')`.

> I'm thinking of using Model.get_or_insert to make sure that old records don't get overwritten, but is there a way to tell if the return value is newly created or pre-existing? I want to be able to display an error message if the user entered a duplicate name.

Use `Model.get_by_id()`. It will return a model instance or `None` if a model is not found:

```py
profile = UserProfile.get_by_id('my_unique_name')
if profile:
    # display error message saying that the user already exists.
```

> Lastly, I tried to create a key_name field on a DjangoForms model that uses the above ndb model as the metaclass so I can use djangoforms for validation/rendering but for some reason my defined fields don't show up.

I don't know how DjangoForms work, but most likely they are not compatible with NDB. You will want to create your own validation logic.

Comment: Your solution to part 2 won't work if he wants to create the user transactionally if it doesn't already exist - a transaction is required for that.

Comment: @NickJohnson what would you suggest? To override `Model.get_or_insert()` and to raise an exception inside the transaction if get part returns user?

Comment: I'd suggest implementing a transaction that does exactly what's needed - attempt to get the model; throw an error if it exists, and create it if it doesn't.