# Google App engine: No key_name attribute

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I'm trying to learn how the GAE, most things are working, but for some strange reason, this code outputs a

```
AttributeError: 'User_Account' object has no attribute 'key_name'
```

Here's the two code extracts that are relevant:

```
class User_Account(ndb.Model):
    name = ndb.StringProperty()
    firstname = ndb.StringProperty()


class AddUser(webapp2.RequestHandler):

    def get(self):
        test_user = User_Account(name = "snow", firstname ="jon", key_name="jon")
```

I've tried it with db and ndb model, it doesn't work either way...

Thanks in advance for any answer.

UPDATE: Here's the "full" code (i removed all the other un-necessary parts):

```
import webapp2
import cgi
from google.appengine.ext import ndb


MAIN_PAGE_HTML = """\
<html>
  <body>
    <br/>
    <a href="/add_user"> Add a user </a>
  </body>
</html>
"""

class Comment(ndb.Model):
    content = ndb.StringProperty()

class User_Account(ndb.Model):
    name = ndb.StringProperty()
    firstname = ndb.StringProperty()
    comments = ndb.KeyProperty(repeated=True)


class AddUser(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        test_user = User_Account(name = "jon", firstname ="snow", key_name="jon")
        self.response.write(test_user.key_name + "<br/>")

        test_user.put()

        self.response.write("User added")

class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.response.write(MAIN_PAGE_HTML)


application = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/', MainPage),
    ('/add_user', AddUser)
], debug=True)
```

MOAR EDIT:
Even this very simple code, when executed in the dev console, outputs an error

```
import os
import pprint

from google.appengine.ext import ndb

class Comment(ndb.Model):
    content = ndb.StringProperty()


test_comment = Comment(content="Hello world", key_name="hello")
test_comment.put()
```

Comment: The code you've posted runs fine. There must be something you're not sharing.

Comment: Instead of key_name use id. See the answer from this question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10215676/whats-the-best-way-to-specify-a-key-name-for-app-engine-ndb-model

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please read documentation for the `ndb` Model class. Specifically on the model constructor arguments. https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/modelclass#Constructor

You will see it takes `id`, rather `than key_name`.  `key_name` is a constructor argument for `db` api.

Comment: Thanks , it does work now. I bought a book on GAE and it's mostly about the old "db" module api (o'reilly edition)... Since i couldn't find any real example in the Official doc, i kind of fell back to the old one where this functionnality was truly documented.

Comment: Google brought me to this question (and answer). I had the same problem from the same sample code in the same book.

Answer (score 0):

I had a solution to a similar case where I wanted the key_name of an entity (which had key_name only and no ID). I was able to find the key_name from the property `self.key().name()`